# loading an image from my .json file to my product detailpage in vue js

Tags: javascript, json, axios, frontend, vuejs3

I am trying to render an image from my JSON file in VUE but its not working was making a product detail page and display each product detail depending on the one selected on that page ...so this is the code for that page .I have tried using the require function to load the image but its still not .the image is in my images folder under the assets folder...here is the code..

```
`<template>
  <Header />
  <div class="title">

    <h1>Product Description</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="container mb-5">
    <hr />

    <div class="card">
      <div class="row">
        <aside class="col-sm-5 border-right">
          <article class="gallery-wrap">
            <div class="img-big-wrap">
              <div>
                <img :src="require(`../assets/images/${product.image}`)" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- slider-product.// -->

            <!-- slider-nav.// -->
          </article>
          <!-- gallery-wrap .end// -->
        </aside>
        <aside class="col-sm-7">
          <article class="card-body p-5">
            <h3 class="title mb-3">{{ product.name }}</h3>

            <p class="price-detail-wrap">
              <span class="price h3 text-warning">
                <span class="currency">US $</span
                ><span class="num">{{ product.price }}</span>
              </span>
            </p>
            <!-- price-detail-wrap .// -->
            <dl class="item-property">
              <dt>Description</dt>
              <dd>
                <p>
                  {{ product.description }}
                </p>
              </dd>
            </dl>
            <dl class="param param-feature">
              <dt>Model#</dt>
              <dd>12345611</dd>
            </dl>
            <!-- item-property-hor .// -->
            <dl class="param param-feature">
              <dt>Color</dt>
              <dd>Black and white</dd>
            </dl>
            <!-- item-property-hor .// -->
            <dl class="param param-feature">
              <dt>Delivery</dt>
              <dd>Russia, USA, and Europe</dd>
            </dl>
            <!-- item-property-hor .// -->

            <hr />
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <dl class="param param-inline">
                  <dt>Quantity:</dt>
                  <dd>
                    <select
                      class="form-control form-control-sm"
                      style="width: 70px"
                    >
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                  </dd>
                </dl>
                <!-- item-property .// -->
              </div>
              <!-- col.// -->
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                <dl class="param param-inline">
                  <dt>Size:</dt>
                  <dd>
                    <label class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="radio"
                        name="inlineRadioOptions"
                        id="inlineRadio2"
                        value="option2"
                      />
                      <span class="form-check-label">SM</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="radio"
                        name="inlineRadioOptions"
                        id="inlineRadio2"
                        value="option2"
                      />
                      <span class="form-check-label">MD</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="radio"
                        name="inlineRadioOptions"
                        id="inlineRadio2"
                        value="option2"
                      />
                      <span class="form-check-label">XXL</span>
                    </label>
                  </dd>
                </dl>
                <!-- item-property .// -->
              </div>
              <!-- col.// -->
            </div>
            <!-- row.// -->
            <hr />

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary text-uppercase">
              <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart
            </a>
          </article>
          <!-- card-body.// -->
        </aside>
        <!-- col.// -->
      </div>
      <!-- row.// -->
    </div>
    <!-- card.// -->
  </div>
  <!--container.//-->
  <Footer />
</template>
<script>
import Header from "./Header";
import axios from "axios";
import Footer from "./Footer";
export default {
  name: "ProductDetail",
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      product: {},
    };
  },

  async mounted() {
    let result = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:3000/products/" + this.$route.params.id
    );
    this.product = result.data;
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
/* Import Font Dancing Script */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);
.title {
  font-family: "Dancing Script", cursive;
  padding-top: 15px;
  left: 45%;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
</style>`
```

`{`
`"products": [`
`{`
`"id": 1,`
`"name": "shirt",`
`"price": "40",`
`"description": "Product shirt",`
`"image": "f2.jpg",`
`"reviews": [`
`{ " id": 1, " comment": "Good product" },`
`{ "id": 2, "comment": "Excellent product" },`
`{ " id": 3, "comment": "Average product" }`
`]`
`},`
`{`
`"id": 2,`
`"name": "shirt",`
`"price": "40",`
`"description": "Product shirt",`
`"image": "f1.jpg",`
`"reviews": [`
`{ " id": 1, " comment": "Good product" },`
`{ "id": 2, "comment": "Excellent product" },`
`{ " id": 3, "comment": "Average product" }`
`]`
`}`
`]`
`}`

`I expect the image to be rendered on my product detail page...everything is being rendered except from the image`

Comment: this is the part giving me the hard time..... <img :src="require(`../assets/images/${product.image}`)" />

Comment: JSON Derulo...i have also tried using that...but still getting a 404 error despite the path being correct